# How can I create a batch action/macro to show lots of different typefaces to a client"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typefaces

I have prepared a logo for a client and for the typeface I want to just change the type and show him a prepared version of maybe 50 different typefaces that can go alongside the logo?

(Alternatively, are there good tools that can do this for me).

Comment: Hello Layke, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: use smart objects, the action is not useful.

Comment: I, personally, think it's bad form to provide a client *too many* choices. Showing anywhere near 50 typefaces would be silly to me. I'd show 3 at most.

Comment: +1 For Scotts comment. I get dizzy exploring more than 10 fonts... Imagine your client. The designer is you. Make the design desitions. - If you are on the first dates prepare a nice print of some generic examples to see a posible trend. Not aplied to the logo, just font examples.

Comment: I am concernd about you want a program to do it for you. Fonts for a logo is not just swiching fonts. It is insane enough to have 50 opitons. Now you want a program doing it in batch mode instead of seing how it looks, the spacing, proportion, kerning, weight, etc... Really?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. On consideration I agree. Although, I feel like you are down voting the question based not on the merit or (lacking in quality) of the question asked, but on the business implications of overwhelming the client.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would not recommend providing 50 variations for font choices because that would cause too many issues.  I think it would be best to only provide 5 choices at max.

### For web

To answer your question if this is going to become a common practice for you would I consider an HTML page you could call on the image and have your fonts displayed and you could always implement a form that will allow them to select the font so you dont have to sit there.

### For Print

You could generate a PDF template if you dont know how to code or create an action in Photoshop.  With the template you can just add your design to whatever side you like.

This Q&A from the Adobe Forums might help you: [How to set multi fonts in one textItem?](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4990185#4990185)

```
// create a type layer with more than one font;  
// 2013, use at your own risk;  
#target photoshop  
if (app.documents.length > 0) {  
var theText = [  
["this is a text", 12, "Helvetica"],  
["this is another font", 15, "Times-Roman"]  
];  
// create;  
createPointTextMoreCompl (theText, 50, 50);  
};  
////// create point text layer //////  
function createPointTextMoreCompl (theArray, theX, theY) {  
if (theArray[0].length > 0) {  
// join the texts;  
var theText =  new String;  
for (var m = 0; m < theArray.length; m++) {  
theText = theText + " " + theArray[m][0]  
};  
// =======================================================  
var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );  
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();  
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );  
        var ref2 = new ActionReference();  
        var idTxLr = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );  
        ref2.putClass( idTxLr );  
    desc4.putReference( idnull, ref2 );  
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );  
        var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();  
        var idTxt = charIDToTypeID( "Txt " );  
// text;  
        desc5.putString( idTxt, theText );  
        var idwarp = stringIDToTypeID( "warp" );  
            var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();  
            var idwarpStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "warpStyle" );  
            var idwarpStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "warpStyle" );  
            var idwarpNone = stringIDToTypeID( "warpNone" );  
            desc6.putEnumerated( idwarpStyle, idwarpStyle, idwarpNone );  
            var idwarpValue = stringIDToTypeID( "warpValue" );  
            desc6.putDouble( idwarpValue, 0.000000 );  
            var idwarpPerspective = stringIDToTypeID( "warpPerspective" );  
            desc6.putDouble( idwarpPerspective, 0.000000 );  
            var idwarpPerspectiveOther = stringIDToTypeID( "warpPerspectiveOther" );  
            desc6.putDouble( idwarpPerspectiveOther, 0.000000 );  
            var idwarpRotate = stringIDToTypeID( "warpRotate" );  
            var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );  
            var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );  
            desc6.putEnumerated( idwarpRotate, idOrnt, idHrzn );  
        var idwarp = stringIDToTypeID( "warp" );  
        desc5.putObject( idwarp, idwarp, desc6 );  
// position;  
        var idTxtC = charIDToTypeID( "TxtC" );  
            var desc7 = new ActionDescriptor();  
            var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );  
            var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );  
            desc7.putUnitDouble( idHrzn, idPrc, theX );  
            var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );  
            var idPrc = charIDToTypeID( "#Prc" );  
            desc7.putUnitDouble( idVrtc, idPrc, theY );  
        var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );  
        desc5.putObject( idTxtC, idPnt, desc7 );  
        var idtextGridding = stringIDToTypeID( "textGridding" );  
        var idtextGridding = stringIDToTypeID( "textGridding" );  
        var idNone = charIDToTypeID( "None" );  
        desc5.putEnumerated( idtextGridding, idtextGridding, idNone );  
        var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );  
        var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );  
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );  
        desc5.putEnumerated( idOrnt, idOrnt, idHrzn );  
        var idAntA = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );  
        var idAnnt = charIDToTypeID( "Annt" );  
        var idantiAliasSharp = stringIDToTypeID( "antiAliasSharp" );  
        desc5.putEnumerated( idAntA, idAnnt, idantiAliasSharp );  
        var idtextShape = stringIDToTypeID( "textShape" );  
            var list1 = new ActionList();  
                var desc8 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idTEXT = charIDToTypeID( "TEXT" );  
                var idTEXT = charIDToTypeID( "TEXT" );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );  
                desc8.putEnumerated( idTEXT, idTEXT, idPnt );  
                var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );  
                var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );  
                var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );  
                desc8.putEnumerated( idOrnt, idOrnt, idHrzn );  
                var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );  
                    var desc9 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    var idxx = stringIDToTypeID( "xx" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idxx, 1.000000 );  
                    var idxy = stringIDToTypeID( "xy" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idxy, 0.000000 );  
                    var idyx = stringIDToTypeID( "yx" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idyx, 0.000000 );  
                    var idyy = stringIDToTypeID( "yy" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idyy, 1.000000 );  
                    var idtx = stringIDToTypeID( "tx" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idtx, 0.000000 );  
                    var idty = stringIDToTypeID( "ty" );  
                    desc9.putDouble( idty, 0.000000 );  
                var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID( "Trnf" );  
                desc8.putObject( idTrnf, idTrnf, desc9 );  
                var idrowCount = stringIDToTypeID( "rowCount" );  
                desc8.putInteger( idrowCount, 1 );  
                var idcolumnCount = stringIDToTypeID( "columnCount" );  
                desc8.putInteger( idcolumnCount, 1 );  
                var idrowMajorOrder = stringIDToTypeID( "rowMajorOrder" );  
                desc8.putBoolean( idrowMajorOrder, true );  
                var idrowGutter = stringIDToTypeID( "rowGutter" );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                desc8.putUnitDouble( idrowGutter, idPnt, 0.000000 );  
                var idcolumnGutter = stringIDToTypeID( "columnGutter" );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                desc8.putUnitDouble( idcolumnGutter, idPnt, 0.000000 );  
                var idSpcn = charIDToTypeID( "Spcn" );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                desc8.putUnitDouble( idSpcn, idPnt, 0.000000 );  
                var idframeBaselineAlignment = stringIDToTypeID( "frameBaselineAlignment" );  
                var idframeBaselineAlignment = stringIDToTypeID( "frameBaselineAlignment" );  
                var idalignByAscent = stringIDToTypeID( "alignByAscent" );  
                desc8.putEnumerated( idframeBaselineAlignment, idframeBaselineAlignment, idalignByAscent );  
                var idfirstBaselineMinimum = stringIDToTypeID( "firstBaselineMinimum" );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                desc8.putUnitDouble( idfirstBaselineMinimum, idPnt, 0.000000 );  
                var idbase = stringIDToTypeID( "base" );  
                    var desc10 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );  
                    desc10.putDouble( idHrzn, 0.000000 );  
                    var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );  
                    desc10.putDouble( idVrtc, 0.000000 );  
                var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "Pnt " );  
                desc8.putObject( idbase, idPnt, desc10 );  
            var idtextShape = stringIDToTypeID( "textShape" );  
            list1.putObject( idtextShape, desc8 );  
        desc5.putList( idtextShape, list1 );  
        var idTxtt = charIDToTypeID( "Txtt" );  
            var list2 = new ActionList();  
                var desc11 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );  
// from;  
                desc11.putInteger( idFrom, 0 );  
                var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );  
// to;  
                desc11.putInteger( idT, theArray[0][0].length + 1);  
                var idTxtS = charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" );  
                    var desc12 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    var idstyleSheetHasParent = stringIDToTypeID( "styleSheetHasParent" );  
                    desc12.putBoolean( idstyleSheetHasParent, true );  
                    var idfontPostScriptName = stringIDToTypeID( "fontPostScriptName" );  
// font;  
                    desc12.putString( idfontPostScriptName, theArray[0][2] );  
/*                    var idFntN = charIDToTypeID( "FntN" );  
                    desc12.putString( idFntN, """Arial""" );  
                    var idFntS = charIDToTypeID( "FntS" );  
                    desc12.putString( idFntS, """Regular""" );*/  
                    var idScrp = charIDToTypeID( "Scrp" );  
                    desc12.putInteger( idScrp, 0 );  
                    var idFntT = charIDToTypeID( "FntT" );  
                    desc12.putInteger( idFntT, 1 );  
                    var idSz = charIDToTypeID( "Sz  " );  
                    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
// size;  
//                    desc12.putUnitDouble( idSz, idPnt, theArray[0][1] * (Math.random() * 0.4 + 0.8) );  
                    desc12.putUnitDouble( idSz, idPnt, theArray[0][1] );  
                    var idTrck = charIDToTypeID( "Trck" );  
                    desc12.putInteger( idTrck, 15 );  
                    var iddigitSet = stringIDToTypeID( "digitSet" );  
                    var iddigitSet = stringIDToTypeID( "digitSet" );  
                    var iddefaultDigits = stringIDToTypeID( "defaultDigits" );  
                    desc12.putEnumerated( iddigitSet, iddigitSet, iddefaultDigits );  
                    var idmarkYDistFromBaseline = stringIDToTypeID( "markYDistFromBaseline" );  
                    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                    desc12.putUnitDouble( idmarkYDistFromBaseline, idPnt, 5.760000 );  
                    var idtextLanguage = stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" );  
                    var idtextLanguage = stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" );  
                    var idgermanLanguageReformedonenineninesix = stringIDToTypeID( "germanLanguageReformed1996" );  
                    desc12.putEnumerated( idtextLanguage, idtextLanguage, idgermanLanguageReformedonenineninesix );  
                    var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );  
                        var desc13 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                        var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );  
                        desc13.putDouble( idRd, 0 );  
                        var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );  
                        desc13.putDouble( idGrn, 0 );  
                        var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );  
                        desc13.putDouble( idBl, 0 );  
                    var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );  
                    desc12.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc13 );  
                var idTxtS = charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" );  
                desc11.putObject( idTxtS, idTxtS, desc12 );  
            var idTxtt = charIDToTypeID( "Txtt" );  
            list2.putObject( idTxtt, desc11 );  
// if more than one array;  
// add the string’s lengths;   
var theCounter = theArray[0][0].length + 1;  
for (var n = 1; n < theArray.length; n++) {  
                var desc14 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );  
// from;  
                desc14.putInteger( idFrom, theCounter );  
                var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );  
theCounter = theCounter + 1 + theArray[n][0].length;  
// to;  
                desc14.putInteger( idT, theCounter );  
                var idTxtS = charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" );  
                    var desc15 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    var idstyleSheetHasParent = stringIDToTypeID( "styleSheetHasParent" );  
                    desc15.putBoolean( idstyleSheetHasParent, true );  
                    var idfontPostScriptName = stringIDToTypeID( "fontPostScriptName" );  
// font;   
                    desc15.putString( idfontPostScriptName, theArray[n][2] );  
                    var idScrp = charIDToTypeID( "Scrp" );  
                    desc15.putInteger( idScrp, 0 );  
                    var idFntT = charIDToTypeID( "FntT" );  
                    desc15.putInteger( idFntT, 0 );  
                    var idSz = charIDToTypeID( "Sz  " );  
                    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
// size;  
                    desc15.putUnitDouble( idSz, idPnt, theArray[n][1] );  
                    var idTrck = charIDToTypeID( "Trck" );  
                    desc15.putInteger( idTrck, 15 );  
                    var iddigitSet = stringIDToTypeID( "digitSet" );  
                    var iddigitSet = stringIDToTypeID( "digitSet" );  
                    var iddefaultDigits = stringIDToTypeID( "defaultDigits" );  
                    desc15.putEnumerated( iddigitSet, iddigitSet, iddefaultDigits );  
                    var idmarkYDistFromBaseline = stringIDToTypeID( "markYDistFromBaseline" );  
                    var idPnt = charIDToTypeID( "#Pnt" );  
                    desc15.putUnitDouble( idmarkYDistFromBaseline, idPnt, 5.760000 );  
                    var idtextLanguage = stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" );  
                    var idtextLanguage = stringIDToTypeID( "textLanguage" );  
                    var idgermanLanguageReformedonenineninesix = stringIDToTypeID( "germanLanguageReformed1996" );  
                    desc15.putEnumerated( idtextLanguage, idtextLanguage, idgermanLanguageReformedonenineninesix );  
                    var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );  
                        var desc16 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                        var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );  
                        desc16.putDouble( idRd, 0 );  
                        var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );  
                        desc16.putDouble( idGrn, 0 );  
                        var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );  
                        desc16.putDouble( idBl, 0 );  
                    var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );  
                    desc15.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc16 );  
                var idTxtS = charIDToTypeID( "TxtS" );  
                desc14.putObject( idTxtS, idTxtS, desc15 );  
            var idTxtt = charIDToTypeID( "Txtt" );  
            list2.putObject( idTxtt, desc14 );  
          };  
        desc5.putList( idTxtt, list2 );  
////////////////////////////////////  
        var idparagraphStyleRange = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyleRange" );  
            var list3 = new ActionList();  
                var desc17 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                var idFrom = charIDToTypeID( "From" );  
                desc17.putInteger( idFrom, 0 );  
                var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );  
// to;  
                desc17.putInteger( idT, theText.length*2);  
                var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );  
                    var desc18 = new ActionDescriptor();  
                    var idstyleSheetHasParent = stringIDToTypeID( "styleSheetHasParent" );  
                    desc18.putBoolean( idstyleSheetHasParent, true );  
                    var idAlgn = charIDToTypeID( "Algn" );  
                    var idAlg = charIDToTypeID( "Alg " );  
                    var idCntr = charIDToTypeID( "Cntr" );  
                    desc18.putEnumerated( idAlgn, idAlg, idCntr );  
                    var idhyphenate = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenate" );  
                    desc18.putBoolean( idhyphenate, true );  
                    var idhyphenateWordSize = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenateWordSize" );  
                    desc18.putInteger( idhyphenateWordSize, 8 );  
                    var idhyphenatePreLength = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenatePreLength" );  
                    desc18.putInteger( idhyphenatePreLength, 3 );  
                    var idhyphenatePostLength = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenatePostLength" );  
                    desc18.putInteger( idhyphenatePostLength, 3 );  
                    var idhyphenateLimit = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenateLimit" );  
                    desc18.putInteger( idhyphenateLimit, 2 );  
                    var idhyphenationZone = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenationZone" );  
                    desc18.putDouble( idhyphenationZone, 36.000000 );  
                    var idhyphenateCapitalized = stringIDToTypeID( "hyphenateCapitalized" );  
                    desc18.putBoolean( idhyphenateCapitalized, true );  
                    var idburasagari = stringIDToTypeID( "burasagari" );  
                    var idburasagari = stringIDToTypeID( "burasagari" );  
                    var idburasagariStandard = stringIDToTypeID( "burasagariStandard" );  
                    desc18.putEnumerated( idburasagari, idburasagari, idburasagariStandard );  
                    var idtextEveryLineComposer = stringIDToTypeID( "textEveryLineComposer" );  
                    desc18.putBoolean( idtextEveryLineComposer, true );  
                var idparagraphStyle = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyle" );  
                desc17.putObject( idparagraphStyle, idparagraphStyle, desc18 );  
            var idparagraphStyleRange = stringIDToTypeID( "paragraphStyleRange" );  
            list3.putObject( idparagraphStyleRange, desc17 );  
        desc5.putList( idparagraphStyleRange, list3 );  
        var idkerningRange = stringIDToTypeID( "kerningRange" );  
            var list4 = new ActionList();  
        desc5.putList( idkerningRange, list4 );  
    var idTxLr = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );  
    desc4.putObject( idUsng, idTxLr, desc5 );  
executeAction( idMk, desc4, DialogModes.NO );  
}  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Most font management software have this functionality. For example I am using [NexusFont](http://www.xiles.net/) and it can do this. Off course not a hard thing to do with Photoshop either.

A word of warning, not many people really enjoy shifting 50 fonts. Ive occasionally experimented with peoples sensibilities by giving THEM the choice. And most of the time they get shocked when you present them with more than 5 fonts and think I'm insane. First they wont notice much difference, even if quality wise there's quite a big difference. So in the end you might end up with a font that is not really optimal to the user.

So do your client a favor just show your client only 3-5 fonts tat fulfill some parameters like cost, extended char-set, screen readability etc. Unless your SURE you client is not a connoisseur of fonts.